# How to deploy a Java web application?

Tags: java, web-hosting

I have developed a Java Web Application and I want to show it to my client by hosting it on a server.

I tried to run it on my localpc through web-browser and it worked fine. I gave the hostname as "localhost" in the URL of my webApplication.

Now I want to show it to my client who is on other computer on internet. I tried to replace the "localhost" from my webApplication's url to my current ip address. But when I put that URL on my own browser, it didn't work.

How can I show that web-application to my client.

I have my own domain name but do not own any web-hosting.

I don't want to purchase a web-hosting plan.

---

One more problem:

I don't have static IP address. My IP changes almost everytime when I connect to my ISP.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to replace the "localhost" from my webApplication's url to my current ip address. But when I put that URL on my own browser, it didn't work.

It's impossible to say anything without more details on your network configuration: are you using a router, do you have a firewall, etc. Also, first check that you can use your local IP address (not the loopback address, not the external IP address, your local non routable address).

> I don't have static IP address. My IP changes almost everytime when I connect to my ISP.

That's not a problem and if you don't want to give your "external" IP to your clien each time, you could use a dynamic DNS service like [dyndns.org](http://dyndns.org/) or [no-ip.org](http://no-ip.org).

Answer (score 0):

With your current skill set, I would suggest that you sign up with Google Apps and deploy your Java web application to their cloud.  There are some restrictions but probably not anyone you will have trouble with.

Otherwise you need to poke a hole in your router so others can access your web server.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible only when you have a static IP address.

Comment: Well, it works with a dynamic IP as well. You only need to change the IP everytime when one is about to access it externally.

Comment: Thats exactly why dyndns.org and others exist.